# Fill text box from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows form  i have two combobox and one text box when a jobecode is selected  from cmbjobecode it will load cmbquotationcode  with corresponding quotations and fills a textbox txtamount with amount of selected quotation

all is fine except i cannot get the textbox filled with the amount can anyone help in sorting mistake

```
 private void cmbjobcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboQuotationboxload();
        }

public void comboQuotationboxload()
        {

            OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleDbConnection1.Open();

            OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select quotationpk ,quotationcode , amount from  quotationmastertable  where jobpk = " + cmbjobcode.SelectedValue + "", oleDbConnection1);



            OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("quotationpk", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("quotationcode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));
            dt.Load(reader);
            cmbQuotationcode.ValueMember = "quotationpk";
            cmbQuotationcode.DisplayMember = "quotationcode";
            cmbQuotationcode.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            txtamount.text= "amount";


            oleDbConnection1.Close();

        }
```

Comment: sreenath I pasted a code example down below for you OleDbDataReader can yield some awesome results when utilized properly.. if you need help please feel free to reach out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create dt at class scope

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

/// Add columns to Table at Form_Load()

```
    dt.Columns.Add("quotationpk", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("quotationcode", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));
```

//Then do fill operation

```
 private void cmbjobcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboQuotationboxload();
        }

public void comboQuotationboxload()
        {

            OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleDbConnection1.Open();

            OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select quotationpk ,quotationcode , amount from  quotationmastertable  where jobpk = " + cmbjobcode.SelectedValue + "", oleDbConnection1);



            OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(reader);
            cmbQuotationcode.ValueMember = "quotationpk";
            cmbQuotationcode.DisplayMember = "quotationcode";
            cmbQuotationcode.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;



            oleDbConnection1.Close();

        }
```

//filter data and display in the text box

```
 private void cmbQuotationcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dvDataTable = new DataView(dt);
dvDataTable.RowFilter = "quotationpk ='" + cmbQuotationcode.SelectedValue "'";
if(dvDataTable.Count > 0)
{
 txtamount.Text= Convert.ToString(dvDataTable["amount"]);
}
else
{ 
txtamount.Text = "0";
}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried getting at the table.Rows?

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
        dt.Columns.Add("quotationpk", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("quotationcode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));
 //then you could assign the textbox like this
 txtamount.text= (string)row["amount"];
```

Something like this should lead you to the correct answer
also are you always expecting to get only 1 amount..? if not then you need to wrap that code in a loop..

*** Personally I would use an OleDbDataReader it will read the column and fields instead of having to add the fields like you are..

here is an example of how you could use the OleDbDataReader
I have a method I have written to GetNames from a DataBase for example

```
public void comboQuotationboxload()
{
     OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
     oleDbConnection1.Open();

     OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select quotationpk ,quotationcode , amount from  quotationmastertable  where jobpk = " + cmbjobcode.SelectedValue + "", oleDbConnection1);

     OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
     reader.Read();
     cmbQuotationcode.ValueMember = "quotationpk";
     cmbQuotationcode.DisplayMember = "quotationcode";
     cmbQuotationcode.DataSource = reader;
     txtamount.text = reader["amount"].ToString();
     oleDbConnection1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use DataTable.

Assuming there is only one row returned you can do that:

```
public void comboQuotationboxload()
{
    OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
    oleDbConnection1.Open();
    OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select quotationpk ,quotationcode , amount from  quotationmastertable  where jobpk = " + cmbjobcode.SelectedValue + "", oleDbConnection1);
    OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader.Read())
        return;

    cmbQuotationcode.ValueMember = "quotationpk";
    cmbQuotationcode.DisplayMember = "quotationcode";
    cmbQuotationcode.DataSource = reader;
    txtamount.text = reader["amount"].ToString();

    oleDbConnection1.Close();
}
```